# when do we have to create proxy service and when do we need to create Rest Api?

Tags: api, proxy, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

Soap service in wso2 esb can be created in two ways one way is via creating a custom proxy service and another way is by creating a API. by using custom proxy and Api we can create the soap service so i want to understand when do i create custom proxy and when do i create API.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy service if you need to :

- consume JMS messages (JMS Proxy)
- consume files (VFS Proxy)
- receive SOAP messages (publish a webService with it's WSDL)

Use an API if you need to publish a REST service (generaly, you want to send XML or JSON to such a service)

Have a look there : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Creating+APIs

Comment: Thanks Jean,basically to create soap service we use proxy service(Custom Proxy) and to create REST Apis we use REST Api rite?

Comment: yes, even if you can create a REST service with a custom proxy, APIs is the best way

Comment: You can use APIs if you want to expose your service as a REST service (i.e expose get/post/put/delete methods).

Answer (score 0):

That is depend on your requirement. If you want to expose your service as a REST service (i.e expose via HTTP methods get/post/put/delete) you can use API's. Similarly if you want to expose your service as a web-service you can use proxies. 
You can also proxy a REST service via proxy.

Comment: http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/ Is a good read